# Сумма элементов массива, расположеных между первым и последним отрицательными элементами

Tags: c

Здравствуйте, столкнулась с вот такой вот проблемой. В универе дали сделать лабу по Си, первую часть задания я сделала по нахождению нечетных элементов,а вторую нет. Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

Условие:В одномерном массиве, состоящем из и вещественных элементов, вычислить:

- сумму элементов массива с нечетными номерами;
- сумму элементов массива, расположенных между первым и последним отрицательными элементами.

вот мое первое решение

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main () 
{
    int array[10], i, sum=0, min=0;
    printf("Vvedite 10 chisel\n");
    for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("chislo %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &array[i]); 
    }
    for (i=0; i<10;i++)
    { 
        if(array[i]%2!=0) sum+=array[i]; 
    }
        printf("Summa ne chetnix = %d", sum);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Это что такое `if(array[i]%2!=0)`? Здесь проверяется на чётность элемент массива, а не его индекс. Должно быть `if( i%2 != 0)`.

Comment: Первую часть вы неправильно сделали, надо найти сумму элементов с нечетными номерами, а вы нашли сумму нечетных элементов.
A по второй что не понятно? Как найти индекс первого отрицательного элемента? Как найти индекс последнего отрицательного элемента? Как посчитать сумму элементов лежащих между двумя индексами?

Comment: не знаю как посчитать сумму между первым и последним и как найти их, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @LovelyCat, например можно начинать  считать сумму S1, как только встретился отрицательный элемент. (этот подсчет (примерно 4 строки кода) можно вставить прямо в Ваш цикл, где считается сумма элементов с нечетными номерами).

На втором шаге надо считать сумму S2, двигаясь в обратном порядке, от последнего элемента, пока не встретится отрицательный. Он будет последним отрицательным.

Очевидно, что второй шаг надо делать только если S1 считали (т.е. был хотя бы один отрицательный элемент).

Искомая сумма S = S1 - S2;

Comment: Не могли бы вы показать в качестве примера как ищется S1 ?

Comment: @LovelyCat, что-то в таком роде

    double s1 = 0;
    int calculate_s1 = 0; // начальное значение - не считать S1

    for (i=0; i<10;i++) { // Ваш цикл
       ...
       if (array[i] < 0)
         calculate_s1 = 1; // начнем считать (или продолжим, если уже считали...)
       if (calculate_s1)
         s1 += array[i];
    }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По второму вопросу:

```
int first, last;
for( first = 0; first < 10; first++ )
{
  if( array[first] < 0 ) break;
}
for( last = 9; last > first; last-- )
{
  if( array[last] < 0 ) break;
}
for( i = first+1; i < last; i++ )
{
  sum += array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(void)
{
    float x[15],s1,s2;
    int i,i1,i2;
    s1=0;
    s2=0;
    printf("Massivi do pereobrazovaniya\n\n");
    for (i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
       if (i%2==0)
          x[i]=(-1.0)*sin(exp((7.0-(float)i)/(7.0+(float)i)));
        else
          x[i]=sin(exp((7.0-(float)i)/(7.0+(float)i)));
    }
         for(i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
      printf("%12.5e\t",x[i]);
      if((i+1)%5==0)
      printf("\n");
    }
      for(i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        if(i%2!=0)
        s1=s1+x[i];
    }
    printf("\nsumma elementov s nechotnimi nomerami\t%12.5e",s1);

for(i=0;i<15;i++)
{
if(x[i]<0)
i1=i;
}
for( i=15;i>0;i--)
{
if(x[i]<0)
i2=i;
}
for(i=s2; i<s1; i++)
{
 s2+=x[i];
}
printf("\nsumma elementov mezhdu pervim i poslednim otrisatelnimi elementami=%12.5e",s2);
getc();
}
```

Comment: Рекомендую добавить текстовое описание предложенного кода